# What is the correct way to implement this dynamic inheritance-like structure in Python?

Tags: python, dynamic, multiple-inheritance

I'm implementing part of a test library for a web tool. The user (or in this case, the test) interacts with the web tool through "sessions". There are certain steps the test must take to configure and initialize a session before it can be used in the browser. These steps differ depending on the test configuration. This configuration is specified either on the command line or in a config file, so the session initialization needs to determine what to do at runtime.

After doing some research, I think the most appropriate design pattern is multiple inheritance via an abstract base class and mixins. All methods in the ABC must be implemented to have a functional session class. The mixins each provide functionality specific to their configuration.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class BaseSession(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get_url(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @abstractmethod
    def start_session(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @abstractmethod
    def wait_for_connect(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class LocalMixin:
    def get_url(self):
        ...

    def start_session(self):
        ...

    def wait_for_connect(self):
        ...


class RemoteMixin:
    def wait_for_connect(self):
        ...


class InternalServerMixin:
    valid_instances = ["dev", "build_test", "load_test"]

    def get_url(self):
        ...

    def start_session(self):
        ...

    def edit_server_settings(self):
        ...


class ExternalServerMixin:
     valid_instances = ["beta", "staging", "production"]

    def get_url(self):
        ...

    def start_session(self):
        ...
```

My question is this: **what is the best and most correct way to make use of this structure?** I've thought of two possible options so far:

---

## Option 1:

Explicitly define concrete child classes

```
class LocalSession(LocalMixin, BaseSession):
    def __init__(self):
        ...


class RemoteInternalSession(RemoteMixin, InternalServerMixin, BaseSession):
    def __init__(self):
        ...


class RemoteExternalSession(RemoteMixin, ExternalServerMixin, BaseSession):
    def __init__(self):
        ...


def get_session(tool_type: str, instance: str) -> BaseSession:
    if tool_type == "local":
        return LocalSession()
    elif tool_type == "remote":
        if instance in InternalServerMixin.valid_instances:
            return RemoteInternalSession()
        elif instance in ExternalServerMixin.valid_instances:
            return RemoteExternalSession()
        else:
            raise RuntimeError("Instance '{}' is not valid for tool type 'remote'.".format(instance))
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("Tool type '{}' is not valid.".format(tool_type))
```

---

## Option 2:

Return a single `Session` type which dynamically inherits from the appropriate parent classes

```
def get_session(tool_type: str, instance: str) -> BaseSession:
    if tool_type == "local":
        base_classes = [LocalMixin, BaseSession]
    elif tool_type == "remote":
        if instance in InternalServerMixin.valid_instances:
            base_classes = [RemoteMixin, InternalServerMixin, BaseSession]
        elif instance in ExternalServerMixin.valid_instances:
            base_classes = [RemoteMixin, ExternalServerMixin, BaseSession]
        else:
            raise RuntimeError("Instance '{}' is not valid for tool type 'remote'.".format(instance))
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("Tool type '{}' is not valid.".format(tool_type))

    class Session(base_classes):
        def __init__(self):
            ...
    return Session
```

Or is there a better solution that I haven't thought of?